# Notation ${}_{\mathcal B}[h]_{\mathcal A}$ or $[h]_{\mathcal A}^{\mathcal B}$ for the matrix of a linear map $h$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, notation, index-notation

I've seen a few times the notation ${}_{\mathcal B}[h]_{\mathcal A}$ for the matrix of a linear map $h\colon E\to F$ with respect to a base $\mathcal A$ of $E$ and a base $\mathcal B$ of $F$.
I imagine that the notation for the column of coordinates of an element $v$ of $E$ in the base $\mathcal A$ is then ${}_{\mathcal A}[v]$.

This notation is quite practical indeed:
$$
{}_{\mathcal B}[h(v)]
= {}_{\mathcal B}[h]_{\mathcal A}{}_{\mathcal A}[v],\quad
{}_{\mathcal C}[kh]_{\mathcal A}
= {}_{\mathcal C}[k]_{\mathcal B}{}_{\mathcal B}[h]_{\mathcal A}.
$$

I've though also of a possible alternative notation inspired by [Ricci calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_calculus) conventions: $[h]_{\mathcal A}^{\mathcal B}$ could denote the matrix of $h\colon E\to F$ and $[v]^{\mathcal A}$ could denote the column of coordinates of $v\in E$, and then
$$
[h(v)]^{\mathcal B}
= [h]_{\mathcal A}^{\mathcal B}[v]^{\mathcal A},\quad
[kh]_{\mathcal A}^{\mathcal C}
= [k]_{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal C}[h]_{\mathcal A}^{\mathcal B}.
$$

Is there some reputable textbook on linear algebra or a related topic that uses some such notation?

---

**Relevant observations**

Serge Lang in his *Linear Algebra* used the notation $M^{\mathcal A}_{\mathcal B}(h)$ for the matrix of $h$ and $X_{\mathcal A}(v)$ for the column of coordinates of $v$, thus making the opposite choice of lower and upper indices to what I suggest.  The use of upper and lower indices in matrices in his book is also opposite to that of Ricci calculus.

Comment: A Course in Linear Algebra by Damiano & Little uses the latter notation. I once taught an undergraduate course using it as text. That is why I remembered. Pretty sure other introductory courses use it too.

Comment: @NDB, thanks for the reference. However, they are not quite consistent: they write $[v]_{\mathcal B}$ for vector coordinates.

Comment: Anton and Rorres's Linear Algebra uses $[h]_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{A}}$ for this (and uses $[v]_{\mathcal{A}}$ for vector coordinates in the domain, and even highlights the version of a 'cancellation law' that emerges when you use this notation, see e.g. Section 8.4 of the 11th edition). While I'd expect the "Ricci-inspired" choice to be more common than it is, I understand why there is little standardization in this area (roughly speaking, there is a baseline level of notational difficulty whenever multiple coordinates are in use, and no convention significantly changes what that level is)